# Can't serve static file in wwwroot directory under .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a new project (type Web API) and noticed afterwards that it'd be nice to have some static pages in it, so I added *index.html* to the directory called *wwwroot*.

I've followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) and made sure that the package *Microsoft.AspNetCore.All* is installed (version 2.0.8). I also added *app.UseStaticFiles()* in the configuration method.

When I run the program, I can access the demo values through the controller, so I'm concluding that the service is up and working. However, when I try to access the index file using the URL suggested on the webpage (i.e. *localhost:port/index.html*), I'm hitting 404.

What am I missing?

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Right now I am guessing:
1) try rename index.html to static.html
2) How does your route looks?

Comment: I was following the previous comments. What happened when you tried `UseDefaultFiles`?

Comment: I would also suggest checking your routes to see if they are not catching the static file request (route conflict)

Comment: @Nkosi Nothing happened to it. It's not relevant to this case. The docs explain what *UseDefaultFiles* does - it's for the router to **assume** that the file to look for is *index.html* etc. if not specified. That's not the case as can be inferred from the URL I've posted in my question. Let me check the router part. I'm not sure if it might be that, because I target the root and get 404 but who knows...

Comment: You should look at the web server log file to see the actual path requested. Also, the [sub-code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0) of the 404 error might be useful to you.

Comment: What does the IIS Manager say about your deployed folder and any mapping or virtual path?  It doesn't look like an authentication problem, but it might be something about the mapping.  I would look at whatever IIS Manager can tell you, and add that to your question.

Comment: Can I safely presume when you say `localhost:port/index.html` that you are actually typing in the port number `http://localhost:31544/index.html`? beyond that, try creating another page called `foo.html` and see if that works.  Often web servers are set to redirect `/`, `/index.[htm|html|php|asp|etc.]` to your servers default server page e.g. `index.aspx`

Comment: Telling us you've followed some off-site guide (even if it's Microsoft) without telling us *exactly* what you did do (*in the question*) isn't sufficient. While links to external resources can be used as supplemental information, the question must be self-contained (i.e. enough information to duplicate the problem must be in the question). In addition, there doesn't appear to be enough information here to duplicate the problem. Without that information, we get what's happening here, which is that people can just guess at what the problem is, instead of actually determine what the problem is.

Comment: @Makyen are you suggesting that he post all of his codes for us to reproduce the error?
To your questions I can answer that (even if I'm not the creator of this post)

1) He created a new project(could be a test, could be anything, but its a new project)
2) He followed a guide based on a website. That site contains the code that he used in here, he actually copy pasted the codes from the site, modified it, then tested it on his project.
3) Now he encounters an error 404 when he used the code from that site?
Best guess? maybe because he copy pasted the site exactly as it was written.

Comment: @Mr.J Yes, I'm saying that, as is stated in the [help/on-topic], debugging questions *must* contain enough information to duplicate the problem *in the  question itself*, or they are off-topic (along with meeting the other requirements). In addition,  A) You're just guessing for a both what the OP did and what's causing the error. B) If the link containing the guide goes away (they do, even from large companies), then you have little knowledge of what the OP was *supposed* to do. C) We don't know what the OP *actually* did, because they haven't told us.

Comment: @Makyen I'm sure even though those details are added, someone else will scream too broad, lacking info, etc. because these questions are somehow personalized..

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for your comments. While I agree with you in the principal matter, I wonder what you'd suggest to do in case the error is hard to reproduce or, even better, when I'm not able to reproduce the error but not sure why. Sometimes, the problem is outside the competence reach of a developer. Sometimes, it's just something weird and falls on diagnostic skills (or lack thereof). Obviously, I too support clear, to-the-point, reproducible questions **but** as any experienced developer knows, sometimes, the computer is being a dick. What's your recommendation for digesting such?

Answer (score 0):

Something you might have missed is that the order in which you register the static middleware matters.

Try moving your `app.UseStaticFiles();` call to the top of the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method, before the exception handling one.